# Second ajax request doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I made an ajax website calling pages from `/pages` folder inside an `ajax-container` div in my `index.php`.

Now i want to make a second ajax request after the first ajax request success but the second request will be only on certains page,

for example: i call the page `work.php` and inside this page i want to call a page `work-slider` from the same folder and replace the work.php page by work-slider.php in my ajax-container div when i click on images `link-in` 
but i can't find a solution for make it,

This is my actual code:

index.php:

```html
<div id="ajax-container">
 <?php
  $d = "pages/";
  if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
     $p = strtolower($_GET['p']);
     if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/", $p) && file_exists($d . $p . ".php")) {
         include $d . $p . ".php";
     } else {
         include $d . "404.php";
     }
  } else {
     include $d . "home.php";
  }
 ?>
</div>
```

Ajax function:

```js
var afficher = function(data) {

    $('#ajax-container').fadeOut(250, function() {
        $('#ajax-container').empty();
        $('#ajax-container').append(data);
        $('#ajax-container').fadeIn(100, function() {});

    });
};

var lastRequest = null;
if (lastRequest !== null) {
    lastRequest.abort();
}

var loadPage = function(page, storeHistory) {
    if (typeof storeHistory === 'undefined') {
        storeHistory = true;
    }


    lastRequest = $.ajax({
        url: "pages/" + page,
        cache: false,
        success: f$.ajax({
    url: "pages/" + page,
    cache: false,
    success: function(resultFirst) {
        afficher(resultFirst);
        if (storeHistory === true) {
            history.pushState({
                'key': 'value',
                'url': page
            }, '', page);
        }
        $.ajax({
          
          // How can i define pageIn variable ?? 
          
          url: "pages/" + pageIn,
          cache: false,
          success: function(resultSecond) {
             afficher(resultSecond);
          }
      });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        afficher('erreur lors du chagement de la page');
    }
});

    return false;
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
            if (e.state === null) {
                loadPage('home.php');
            } else {
                loadPage(e['state']['url'], false);
            }
        });
    }, 0);
});

  
  // link inside index.php

$('.link').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    loadPage(page);
    return false;
});

  // second link inside called page
  
  $('.link-in').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pageIn = $(this).attr('href');
    loadPage(pageIn);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I have the feeling you're binding some events on the called page even before you call it. You should bind click to link-in after you got the page.

Comment: I just want to make an other ajax request after the first one, like : i call work.php so now from work.php i want to call work-slider.php and so replace work.php by work-slider.php inside ajax-container div in my index.php

Comment: You mean you want to make an ajax call from a php page you're getting on the server side ? Mmmmhhhhh

Comment: yes i want make an ajax call from a php page i called with ajax

Comment: Do .link-in tag exist in the DOM when the page load the first time? Or that tag is being injected into the DOM by the first AJAX call? If so, your issue is to use bind() instead of on().

Comment: @Sergeon : I'm afraid it's on the page returned...

Answer (score 0):

If that .link-in tag if dinamically inserted into the DOM after the page loads, the bind() method will fail: bind() attach listeners to elements it find when called. If you add a new elemenent after the bind call, it will not receive the listener binding.

In order to prevent that when dinamically inserting html code in a page, you should use the on() method:

```
  $('body').on('click' , '.link-in', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var pageIn = $(this).attr('href');
     loadPage(pageIn);
     return false;
  });
```

And now, every .link-in tag you push dinamically inside body will respond to the click listener. A discussion on using on() by default instead of bind() is in fact found in the [bind() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).